# Defining command to be run with dotnet watch

Tags: c#, reactjs, .net-core, jsx, csproj

I have a dotnet core project with a react front-end using neutrino to manage presets and configuration. The build process runs '`yarn build`' to build the jsx files with Babel before it compiles the dotnet code:

```
  <Target Name="PreBuild" BeforeTargets="PreBuildEvent">
    <Exec Command="yarn build" />
  </Target>
```

I have set up my csproj file with the following to watch for changes:

```
  <ItemGroup>
    <Watch Include="**\*.cs" />
    <Watch Include="**\*.jsx" Exclude="node_modules\**\*;build\*" />
  </ItemGroup>
```

When I run the project using '`dotnet watch run`', everything works fine, but the combined length of the build process for both the jsx files and the dotnet project can take a significant amount of time.

Is there a way to configure it so that '`yarn build`' is only run for changes in the jsx files, and it only rebuilds the dotnet portion when the cs files change?

Comment: What's the primary output of your yarn build? a single `.js` file in the output?

Comment: It's two js files, some css files, and an index.html

Answer (score 2):

You can supply custom arguments to `dotnet` instead of `run` to execute a custom msbuild target:

```
dotnet watch msbuild /t:YarnBuild
```

For a target in the project file like:

```
<Target Name="YarnBuild" BeforeTargets="BeforeBuild">
  <Exec Command="yarn build" />
</Target>  
<ItemGroup>
  <Watch Include="**\*.jsx" Exclude="node_modules\**\*;build\*" />
</ItemGroup>
```

Comment: Will that still run the dotnet project? And then when a file changes, ONLY run yarn build?

Comment: Yes this will run only the the yarn build on any (cs/jsx/...) file change on watched files

Comment: Ah I see that I didn't address half of your question

Answer (score 1):

I know this is a little bit late, but I'd like to jump in and add a little bit more to Martin Ullrich's answer.  I would recommend setting up two separate background tasks for watching the two different types of compilations.

In bash:

```
dotnet watch run & # watch C# changes
dotnet watch msbuild /t:YarnBuild & # watch javascript changes
```

Note the `&`, which executes the preceding command in the background.

To bring the background processes to the foreground, first use the `jobs` command to see the background processes.  From there, you can use `fg <processID>` to bring it to the foreground.  CTRL+Z sends it back to the background.

In powershell:

```
Start-Job { dotnet watch run }; # watch C# changes
Start-Job { dotnet watch /t:YarnBuild }; # watch javascript changes
```

I'm not aware of a way of bringing a powershell job to the foreground like in bash, but you CAN read the output using `Receive-Job`.  First, use `Get-Job` to get a list of all running jobs and their IDs.  From there, use `Receive-Job <processID>` to see the output of your job.

I find this approach the most ergonomic, as it saves me the hassle of having to come up with a single-command abomination of doing everything I want.  Using background jobs may result in a few more keystrokes but an easier-to-follow workflow. :)

More info on bash jobs: https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Job-Control-Basics.html

More info on powershell jobs:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_jobs?view=powershell-7.1